# How to create an external database when setting up Django test environment?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, testing

My Django application needs to connect an unmanaged (not by Django) external Postgres database.

For testing my project, I need to create the external DB and tables using raw SQL, and delete the DB afterwards.

From reading the Django documentation, one is able to create your own TestRunner class by using the existing `DiscoverRunner` class. The `setup_test_environment` and `teardown_test_environment` methods could be overridden to execute the SQL in order to create the external DB:

```
from psycopg2 import connect
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    """
    Test runner that helps to setup external db if doesn`t exist.
    """

    def setup_test_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
        conn = connect(database='postgres', host='localhost', user='my_user', password='password123')
        try:
            with conn.cursor() as c:
                query = """CREATE DATABASE "test_db" """
                query += """WITH OWNER = my_user """
                query += """ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default """
                query += """LC_COLLATE = 'en_ZA.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_ZA.UTF-8' """
                query += """CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;"""
                c.execute(query)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            conn.close()

        super(CustomTestRunner, self).setup_test_environment(*args,
            **kwargs)

    def teardown_test_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestRunner, self).teardown_test_environment(*args,
            **kwargs)

        # Delete external database after tests
        try:
            conn = connect(database='postgres', host='localhost', user='my_user', password='password123')
            with conn.cursor() as c:
                query = """DROP DATABASE test_db;"""
                c.execute(query)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            conn.close()
        conn.close()
```

However, when I run the tests, I get the following error message:

`CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block`

Is it possible to run and commit SQL within a Django TestRunner? If not, where is the appropriate place to create such an external DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some database commands such as `CREATE DATABASE` can't run within a transaction. You'll need to set the proper isolation level on your database connection:

```
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```

See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#isolation-level-constants.

It is also possible to run and commit SQL within a test runner. The more appropriate places to do this would be in the `setup_databses` and `teardown_databases` methods. Here's an example

```
def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
    conn = connect(database='postgres', host='localhost', ...)
    try:        
        # set the proper isolation level so CREATE DATABASE works
        conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            # execute SQL in here
            query = 'create database TEST_DB'
            cur.execute(query)
    finally:
        conn.close()

    return super(CustomTestRunner, self).setup_databases(**kwargs)
```

The implementation for `teardown_databases` should be quite similar.

Comment: I've tested your solution, works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just as a footnote, one must remember to return `return super(CustomTestRunner, self).setup_databases(*args, **kwargs)`. Notice the `*args` in super too.